# Highlight border of plotband on mouseover

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to highlight border of plotband on mouseover event with some specific color.

I am not able to find any option to do that.

Also is there a way to select certain plotbands programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch mouseover event on plotband, by [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extension. Then manipulate plotBands, as you need.

```
events: {
                    mouseover:function(){
                        var elem = this.svgElem;

                        elem.attr({
                            'stroke-width':2,
                            'stroke':'red'
                        });
                    }
                }
```